# what type of azure resource should i use for hosting many database

Tags: azure

I have a project where i need to host many Databases, (500 and up)
and i am trying to find what is the best option to manage everything considering all the options this days and the price.

in the past i would have a virtual server that has SQL-SERVER on it, and i would create the database on my own, and that is all.

but today 
i host my current project on AZURE, a simple web server, with SQL server, with one database.

and i do not know what Resource to choose from AZURE
is it the SQL Ware House? or do i need to get a Virtual Machine?
or any other option?

i read all the information i found online, but its mostly confused me.
i hope some one could help me, i would like to know from your experience

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all very much depends on size and load of databases. You have 3 options - you can get a VM yourself and have a SQL server there. You are pretty much in control of what is happening and you can host as many DBs as you want. However you'll be in charge of backups, updates and maintenance. But this is a pretty much fixed price.

Another option is to get SQL Server from Azure - you don't need to think much about backups, encryption, updates and other boring stuff and you can get. You can have up to 5000DBs per server, but you can choose size and performance tier of your databases. However that can be expensive, as you are charged per DB.

Third option is to have [Elastic Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool) - this is basically a pile of DBs that are sharing the same resource. Can be useful if you have a lot of small DBs with small load. This will work out cheaper than just paying per DB on your scale. However might not work if you have very uneven load on some DBs - they can consume all the DTUs and will starve the rest of your DBs from processing power.

So it is up to you what you want to do based on your conditions. Personally I would not go with a VM - too much hassle. I would recommend considering (based on DBs load) a combination of Elastic Pool and a stand-alone DBs.

Comment: each database will be around 2 GB at the start, and will increase by 1 GB a year. anyway i will check it out, thank you.